# pdo_mysql extension is not installed

Tags: magento2, cli, php-pdo

**IT`s a fresh Magento 2.1 files**

Initially all working fine , but after some time its  giving this error

**[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]

  pdo_mysql extension is not installed

 cache:clean [--bootstrap="..."] [types1] ... [typesN]**

[image: error]

As per `localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php` I am using `PHP Version 5.6.30`

```
maddy@maddy:/opt/lampp$ sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql php5.0-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pdo-mysql
E: Unable to locate package php5.0-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php5.0-mysql'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.0-mysql'
maddy@maddy:/opt/lampp$ 
   **Even below command don`t work**
maddy@maddy:/opt/lampp$ sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql php7.0-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pdo-mysql
```

I checked the availability

```
maddy@maddy:~$ sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
[sudo] password for maddy: 
WARNING: Module pdo_mysql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
```

Comment: Have you installed any extension recently?

Comment: restart mysql by this command `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: No not a single file is changed manually , nor i installed any plugin.

Comment: maddy@maddy:/opt/lampp$ sudo service mysql restart
Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.

Comment: try `sudo service mysqld start`

Comment: Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63326/discussion-between-saurabh-ranjan-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

type this in your terminal. this is because of missing php-mysql

For php7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql
```

For php5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mysql
```